# Delimiting a input file by 2 delimiters

Tags: c++, file, input, delimiter

I have to read in a file where the first character in the line is the name of the object, and the second character (separated by a space) is the data for that object.

I was wondering how to read in (in C++) each of those pieces of data into different vectors one by one.

Comment: What have you tried? Where's the [mcve] of your attempt? How did, or didn't, your attempt work? And can you please copy-paste en excerpt from the file you want to read? And perhaps refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: `std::ifstream in("in.txt"); in >> some_str;`?

Comment: If you have only two characters in a line, how can there be a space separator in between?

Comment: Please include an example of the contents of the text file.

Comment: Also, there are many examples of reading comma-separated values (csv) formatted text files that should serve as an adequate example for you to use.  Try searching for csv.  Most implementations will let you specify a space as the delimiter instead of a space.

Answer (score 0):

You're lucky, I'm in the code writing mood...

Getting strings line by line:

```
std::ifstream file(path);
if(file) // opened successfully?
{
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(file, line))
    {
        // use line
    }
    if(file.eof())
    {
        // entire file read, file was OK
    }
    else
    {
        // some error occured! need appropriate handling
    }
}
```

Splitting the strings:

```
std::string s   = "hello   world";
auto keyEnd     = std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), isspace);
auto valueBegin = std::find_if(i, s.end(), isalnum);

std::string key(s.begin(), keyEnd);
std::string value(valueBegin, s.end());
```

You could now check both key and value for valid format, e. g. both containing exactly one character, and reject the file if invalid...

Two vectors? You could `push_back` both key and value, but maybe `std::map<std::string, std::string>` (or `std::unordered_map`) is the better choice? Or even `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>`? All of these have the advantage that they keep key and value together and would be more apprpriate, unless you intend to maintain both independently (e. g. sorting the keys while values may/shall keep original order).